# How to use out=STDOUT, err=STDERR in Cucumber::Cli::Main to display output in HTML

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jruby

I am running a cucumber script by executing:

```
Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!
```

I am trying to get the output from Cucumber into a variable, and display it on the screen. I made it work by creating a file, doing:

```
Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!
```

to output the contents to the file, read from the file, and display it.

```
require 'cucumber'

output = File.open('index.html', 'w+')
features = "features/login.feature"
@args = features.split.concat %w(--format html)
Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(@args, out=output).execute!
```

[Here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb) is the source code.

[image]

1. What happens when cucumber outputs to both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`? How can I read from both files?
2. What happens when an exception is raised in the middle of the cucumber script execution? E.g.: Cucumber runs the script. It keeps outputting to `STDOUT`. Suddenly, and error. It breaks. Outputs to `STDERR`. Given that I have to display it on screen, how can I display a normal HTML file on the main screen by reading from both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`?

Answer (score 1):

When a program is run and something appears in the console, it is being sent to STDOUT or STDERR. Typically, STDOUT is where normal output appears (such as results), and STDERR is where error messages are sent. These are [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

The way this function is defined the output will go to STDOUT and STDERR by default, but these could be changed by passing in alternative arguments. This could be the easiest way to capture this data, passing in alternative output streams.